# MYSQL _binary format for UUID

Tags: mysql, uuid

Looking at the general_log table I see queries are being logged as binary uuid (which is fine) but I dont quite understand the format. I can't even find information around this binary representation.

For instance, this binary value `0x46f9c3b997d339ce3bdfecdf0e8d63dd` appears in the log as `_binary'F\xF9ù\x97\xD39\xCE;\xDF\xEC\xDF\x8Dc\xDD'`. I'm failing to see how this is transformed and more important how to transform it back.

Comment: looking at the first few hex characters 0x46f9c3b997...: 46 -> "F", f9 -> "\xF9", c3b9 -> "ù", 97 -> "\x97", ...

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok not that hard, following some comments the only thing that needs to be done is detect \x as hex (next 2 chars), convert rest to HEX similar to mysql HEX function, concat results.